# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Keeps showing for

```
$.when($('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php')).done(function(x){
```

My entire code is

```
$('#menuhome').click(function () {
    $.when($('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php')).done(function (x) {
        $('#middlcolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');
    });
});
```

I'm running out of ideas. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `load` doesn't return a jqXHR object. It returns a jQuery collection. Use the callback function `.load('pages/homemenu.php', fn)`.

Comment: meaning?please explain in detail

Comment: @undefined sir what does fn stands for in the code it says fn is not defined

Comment: It was just a placeholder for a function, use your `done`'s callback function instead of the `fn`. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @undefined by callback meaning `$('#middlcolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');` this one?

Comment: Sorry if my comments were confusing, you have already passed a callback function to the `done` method, what you are referring to is the callback's body, the second parameter of the `load` is a callback function. Please refer to the linked doc.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `load()` function returns jQuery object itself so you cannot pass it as `when()` argument.

Try this code instead:

```
$('#menuhome').click(function() {
    $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php', function() {
        $('#middlcolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');
    });
});
```